# Question about BSpline

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica, mesh, cad

Here is a [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/?1kl3c88zyzd8r3z) with cluster of 3D points. Now we can form a `BSpline` surface out of that.

```
dat=Import["C:\\Users\\Andy\\Desktop\\Foil.mat"];
surface=BSplineFunction[dat];
ParametricPlot3D[surface[x,y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
                MaxRecursion->4,Axes->None,Mesh->All,Boxed->False]
```

Now we can see the structure. But the problem is that I want to make a 3D solid and this structure has actually two visible holes.

[image]

In the next picture we can see that at both corners are open and the structure is not solid but actually hollow.

[image]

So I came up with a solution which I am sure may work visually but does not return a solid structure.

```
pic=Show[Graphics3D[
       {Polygon[Table[surface[0,y],{y,0,1,0.005}]],
        Polygon[Table[surface[1,y],{y,0,1,.005}]]}],
        ParametricPlot3D[surface[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},
           MaxRecursion-> 4,PlotPoints-> 20,
           Mesh-> All],Boxed->False,Axes-> None];
```

GraphicsGrid[
         {{ParametricPlot3D[surface[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},
                           PlotPoints-> 20,Mesh-> All,Boxed->False,Axes-> None],
           Graphics3D[{Polygon[Table[surface[0,y],{y,0,1,0.005}]],
                       Polygon[Table[surface[1,y],{y,0,1,.005}]]}],
          pic}}]

Here goes the output.
[image]

Now we export the third picture where the holes are visually closed as an *.obj file. We can import that file in any CAD based mesh editor like [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/). There one can see the holes to be detected.

[image]

Now is there a simple way so that we can form a solid structure in Mathematica with the given data points in the **Foil.mat** file. I expect some options might be available with in the `BSpline` function to achieve this. As one can expect I want to have a closed surface with no holes.

Hope I have been able to explain my problem explicitly enough. Will wait for your reply.

BR

Answer (score 4):

You may want to explore [`TetGenLink`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/Overview.html), a "hidden feature" in Mathematica.

```
TetGen is a quality tetrahedral mesh generator and a three-dimensional 
Delaunay triangulator.   
TetGenLink is a Mathematica application that uses Wolfram Library Link  
to link to TetGen functions. It is used automatically by Mathematica for  
various operations such as interpolation in three-dimensional convex domains.  
However, it can also be used directly where it gives a flexible and innovative  
way to use the functionality of TetGen.
```

Image from the help:

[image]

Comment: Wasn't this supposed to be kept secret?

Comment: Sounds like time for another community wiki of undocumented stuff :)

Comment: @Verbeia Curiously, it IS documented (enter `TetGenLink/tutorial/Overview` in the help search dialog). The problem is that the doc is not integrated/linked by any other help page.